# Watson Conversation flow going back to root, flow pasted below

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson-conversation

[image]

Why is the conversation going back to [root] node ?

Thank you.

Comment: I have updated @CharlesRankin's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The very first node (to the immediate right of `"Conversation starts"`) is being triggered for your first input (with intent `#DevoxxUS` and `@location:US`).

The next input has an intent of `#whereUS`, however, there is only one child of the previous node, and that child will only trigger on `#whenUS`.

So, the runtime checks the child, which doesn't trigger, and since there are no more children (note it doesn't go down the tree to grandchildren, etc.) it returns back to the root to find an appropriate node.

To prevent Conversation from dropping back to the root node, have the last node in your tree with a condition `true`. This will always be hit, and move you onto the next part of your tree.

For example:

[image]

Typing `Hot` and `Hot` again will return `"One"` and `"Five"`, and your next node will be the branch from `"Five"`.

Comment: Also the first two root nodes have the same condition, that is a bad practice as the first one will always be executed, effectively the second node and all subnodes will always be ignored.

Comment: Thank you, I could understand and fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I spoke with Sandhya and it looks like her app isn't passing in the context to the next request so it falls back to the default response and doesn't continue the conversation. When testing through a REST client, it works fine.